# laravel giving incomprehensible(to me) http exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use laravel 4 and am not able to show a component :
this is a line from my routes

```
Route::resource('/', 'PostsController');
```

and this is my show function from PostsController.php

```
    public function show($id) {
    return "HI";        
}
```

And This is the line that links to the function from my view

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('show/' . $post['id'] ) }}"><h1>{{$post['title']}}</h1></a>
```

And It properly links to `localhost:8000/show/1`
But I'm amazingly getting a `Not found HTTP exception` from laravel.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Your route says that `/` routes to `PostsController`. Unless you have a route set up to handle `/show`, then you aren't routing to `PostsController` from the link you're specifying.

Comment: I'm using resourceful routing , the show/{something:$id} route is already there.

Comment: So you're saying that because you route `/` to `PostsController`, that it implicitly treats what comes after `/` as action, then id?

Comment: For the sake of sanity, have you tried updating to `Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController')` and modifying your link to route to a "classic" path? I'm not saying you should change your URL design--but have you tried that just to make sure something strange isn't happening?

Comment: @NihalSahu That's not how Resource Controller in Laravel works. The `show` method is handling GET requests to `resource/id`. The resource in your case, is `/`

Comment: What if I want it to be like , localhost/show/2or1or whatever and localhost/index for something else

Comment: @NihalSahu then make it something like `Route::resource('show', 'PostsController');`

Comment: Then if I want to invoke create then I'd have to write localhost/show/create

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that @NihalSahu is wrong (me) and that resourceful routing doesn't work like that it would be infinitely better so as to set the router to host/{id}